# Google Apps Provisioning

Tags: .net, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to provision users to Google using Admin SDK API via standalone C# code.

As of now, I am able to search, create & update user in Google however attribute which I am able to push to Google is very basic like first name, last name, primary email ,password or org id however when I am trying passes attribute like phone or email then I am not getting any error but it not getting reflected in Google.

Below the snippet I am using to update user phone number or email (same snippet is working fine if I update user first name or any string attribute).

```
            User user = dirservice.Users.Get("anurag.tripathi@mydomain.com").Execute();
            User newuserbody = new User();

            UserEmail emails = new UserEmail();
            emails.Address = "er.anuragtripathi@mydomain.com";
            emails.Primary = true;
            emails.Type = "personal";

            UserPhone phone = new UserPhone();
            phone.Type = "work";
            phone.Value = "426275674";
            newuserbody.Phones = phone;
            newuserbody.Emails = emails;

            User update = dirservice.Users.Update(newuserbody,user.PrimaryEmail).Execute();

            Console.WriteLine("Post Update"+update.Phones);
```

Please advice correct way to update attriubute like organization, phone or email address.

Comment: In the code, phone should be part of an array, check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update  phones[].value,phones[].type. Once you change the phone, you should be able to update.

Comment: Hi SGC, Thanks for your reply. I have changed phone attribute to array however It giving be error (object reference not set to an instance of an object). I am using below syntax to update phone number .      UserPhone[] phones=new UserPhone[2];
       phones[0].Type= "work";
       phones[0].Value  "426275674";      newuserbody.Phones=phones                                                                    User update = dirservice.Users.Update(newuserbody,user.PrimaryEmail).Execut();

Answer (score 0):

You need JSON arrays.  For Organizations and Phones, incorporate the use of Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray made up of JToken entries.  Then you can set your phones value using

```
newuserbody.Phones = (JArray)phonearray;
```